# String slicing returning unexpected values

Tags: python, slice

I hope this is a simple question! I am trying to reverse a number, and be given the digits in the 'even' positions. When I try to do this within one string slice, I am just given a single digit, even when I am expecing more. When I do it as two slices, I am given the correct answer, but I am unsure why.

For example, if I have the number 512341234, I would expect it to give me 3131, as I have first reversed the string (432143215) and then taken the even position numbers (4[3]2[1]4[3]2[1]5).

Below is the code which I have tried to use to make it work, but doing it as one slice only returns the single digit, whereas doing it as two means it returns the expected value. Why is this?

```
num = 512341234
str(num)[1::-2] #returns 1
str(num)[::-1][1::2] #returns 3131
```

Thanks!
Noah

Comment: the first line says give me the 2nd element and then go left in steps of 2. So 1 is correct. The 2nd statement says step through in steps of -1, then take that and give me every 2nd value, starting at the 2nd value. Split up the 2nd statement to see how it works and print the intermediate result.

Comment: Have you tried walking through the code step by step? _but doing it as one slice only returns the single digit, whereas doing it as two means it returns the expected value._ That's not the only difference, though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1::-2` means to start at position 1 (the second character) and go backwards two characters at a time. You want to start somewhere near the end of the string, e.g.

```
num = 512341234
str(num)[-1::-2]
```

```
'42425'
```

```
num = 512341234
str(num)[-2::-2]
```

```
'3131'
```

But you’ll have to pick `-1` or `-2` based on which one of those characters is in an even position (i.e. based on the length of the string) to do this.

Comment: I don't think that your last sentence is correct. Regardless the length of the string, 
str(num)[-2::-2] will give the correct result

Comment: @IoaTzimas: The question says “even positions”; I thought that might be counting from the start of the string. It could be starting from the least significant digit, though.

Comment: I think the question means "the even positions of the reversed string"